# Symfony2 Routes with prefixed optional values

Tags: php, symfony, routes

there is the following requirement for my url structure.

`/{category}.html`

`/{category}-color-{color}.html`

`/color-{color}.html`

All those urls points to a single controller which generates a filtered view to my catalogue items based on the given filter information. Beside the mentioned category and color filter, there are some more prefixed (e.g. *length-12*) and non-prefixed fragments. The latter have distinct regular expression patterns.

So my question is: Is there a way do solve this requirement with a single route in Symfony2?

What if have currently done:

1. Generate routes for every possible combination.

   - That works but it gives me 15 routes. Adding more filter fragments will result in much more routes.
2. Generate a single route with the path `/{category}{color}{length}.html` and put the prefixes to the requirements.

   - That feels kind of dirty. The url `/color-red.html` gives `[color => 'color-red']` in the matches, so the prefix *'color-'* has to be eleminated manually. On the other hand the generation of urls requires me to put the prefixes to the value (`$router->generate('foo', ['color' => 'color-red']);`) so there are additional steps needed when generating urls based on e.g. database information.
3. Build a stand-alone regular expression that matches all combinations.

   - That also works but it is not using the routing component, so there is no way to use `$router->match()` or `$router->generate()` to work with the urls. The pattern is:

```
/^((?P<category>([a-z]+))(\.html|-))?(length-(?P<length>([1-9][0-9]?))(\.html|-))?(color-(?P<color>([a-z]+))\.html)?$/i
```

Again, is there a way to solve this with a single route without breaking `$router->match()` and `$router->generate()`? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace symfony's default router service with an extended one (aka define a new service with name `@router` that extends `Symfony\Component\Routing\Router`) containing a helper function or an extended `generate()` method.

Then use your solution 2 that is able to match the route without the need to create all those routes manually.

Maybe consider splitting that one route into at least 3 routes. Order is important here as the first matched route wins.

```
/{category}-color-{color}.html
/color-{color}.html
/{category}.html
```

Comment: Now I'm overwriting _match()_ and _generate()_ to do the prefixing stuff on the fly for special marked routes (_$route->setOption('is_filter', true)_). Finally I noticed that I had an error in my Unit Test. The _/{category}{color}{length}.html_ path did not work because of the compile rules of the RoutingCompiler. So I ended up with writing a custom compiler that handles my requirements. THX for your hint!